# Compare mouse movement to the pattern

Tags: mouse, motion, patterns

There are some games where you need to make special movement with your mouse (spell casting or any other action).

**Something like this**
[image]

So basically, how can I compare mouse movement to my pattern (let's say defined by series of points (x, y). I assume there's no need to track the position every frame, there must be an interval.

But in terms of technique, how can I do it?

Comment: I've seen it in an android game called Elementalist. I'm curious about it too. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TenguGames.Elementalist&hl=en

Comment: Did you try [googling mouse gesture recognition](https://www.google.ca/search?q=mouse+gesture+recognition) to get an overview of some of the existing techniques first? Is there a particular technique you've found in your research thus far that you need help implementing?

Comment: If you're using Unity 3D this asset might help you. But if you're not, It will give you some insight.https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/65249

Comment: @DMGregory ugh, I didn't know the name of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this is by using a neural network that has been trained extensively on a lot of data. Draw your own shapes, make your friends draw them etc. It would then be able to guess which one the user tries to draw even if it's not perfect.

More info on how to model a neural network to recognize hand drawn shapes can be found [here](http://www.iioab.org/articles/IIOABJ_7.S5_337-341.pdf)